# Find all matched cell value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro which finds all matched values of a cell in a range. The user enter for example `numb` in the cell A2 Then every time he clicks on `Find` button it will show him the matched cell for example `Order Number` then `purchase number` then `part number` ...

[image]

Here is my code

```
Sub find_matched_cells()
   w = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A4:A104").Find(What:=(w), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False).Activate    
End Sub
```

It works fine but when the user for example press on a cell not in my range then on the button `find` will not work. The issue is in

```
After:=ActiveCell
```

For example if by mistake you selected a cell in a range not in A4:A104 then the ActiveCell will not be in my range and it will give an error.

I need to add condition for example the first ActiveCell Starts from A4 and if I find the first matched cell then ActiveCell will take that value.

Any other suggestions please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is this...

```
Sub find_matched_cells()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A4:A104")
     w = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Rng) Is Nothing Then Range("A4").Select
    Rng.Find(What:=(w), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
     MatchCase:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the intersection. I would re-write the code slightly depending on what you need to actually do to each of these found cells - is it just select them? I have amended code below to avoid error if the value is not found.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, sAddr As String, w

w = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A4:A104")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:=w, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        sAddr = rFind.Address
        Do
            rFind.Select
            MsgBox w & " found at " & rFind.Address
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
         Loop While rFind.Address <> sAddr
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but i want even if activeCell is slected in another range by mistake the macro will show all the matched value. Your code works only if the ActiveCell is in my range

Comment: Have edited above, a different approach, but not really sure what your end objective is.